# Import txt file into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, text, phpmyadmin

Hi how can I import that kind of text file into MySQL data base
Thanks in advance from Quebec City :)

```
"8638671",1,1,"SAL",,,"12.8x16.9 P",,"RC","PFLO",,,
"8638671",2,2,"CUI",,,"10.11x12.6 P",,"RC","LINO",,,
"8638671",3,3,"SDB",,,"3.11x7.3 P",,"RC","LINO",,,
"8638671",4,4,"CCP",,,"8.6x10.2 P",,"RC","LINO",,,
"8638671",5,5,"SDL",,,"5.6x4.4 P",,"RC","LINO",,,
"8640420",1,1,"HAL",,,"5.5x3.3 P",,"RC","CERAM",,,
"8640420",2,2,"SAL",,,"11.1x21.8 P",,"RC","PFLO",,,
"8640420",3,3,"SAM",,,"9x11 P",,"RC","PFLO","porte-patio",,
"8640420",4,4,"CUI",,,"8x7.5 P",,"RC","CERAM",,,
"8640420",5,5,"SDB",,,"5x8 P",,"RC","CERAM",,,
"8640420",6,6,"SDL",,,"5x7.5 P",,"RC","LINO",,,
"8640420",7,7,"CCP",,,"11.5x13 P",,"RC","PFLO",,,
"8640420",8,8,"CAC",,,"9x10 P",,"RC","PFLO",,,
"8640420",9,9,"CAC",,,"7.5x9.10 P",,"RC","PFLO",,,
"8672024",1,1,"CUI",,,"10x8 P",,"RC","AU",,,
"8672024",2,2,"SAM",,,"15x10 P",,"RC","AU",,,
```

Comment: [`MySQL load data infile`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: You can use Data Import tool (CSV or TEXT formats) in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/); data import patterns and command-line mode are supported.

Answer (score 6):

For importing the file, use any server like wamp,xampp. They have the facility called phpMyAdmin which is the GUI for mysql. You can easily import any SQL file from there. Apart from importing the file, it provides many other featues.

Answer (score 2):

1: Open this file in excel, at the time opening the file it will ask you for format. Add there `,`.
2: save that file in `.csv` format.
3: Create your database schema and
4: import `.csv` file through `phpMyAdmin`

Answer (score 0):

Use command like this :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'folder/myFile.txt' INTO TABLE myTable (field1, field2, field3, field4);
```

More info following the @Nemoden link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html